# Mistake in taking second differential

Tags: differential

In my book exercise I need to take total differential of first and second order from function
$$ u=f(t), t = xyz $$
with first order all is good, I get it like that
$$ du = \frac{du}{dt}dt = f'(t)dt $$
$$ dt = yzdx +xzdy+xydz$$
$$ du=f'(t)*(yzdx+xzdy+xydz)$$
but second order does not matchup with answer in the end of the book. I do like that
$$ d^2u = \frac{d^2u}{dt^2}dt^2 = f''(t)dt^2 $$
$$ dt^2= (yzdx +xzdy+xydz)^2$$
$$ d^2u=f''(t)*(yzdx +xzdy+xydz)^2 $$
Answer from book is
$$ d^2u=f''(t)*(yzdx +xzdy+xydz)^2 +2f'(t)*(zdxdy+ydxdz+xdydz) $$
Why does there appear first derivative?

Comment: It's the product rule/chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that 
$$
d^2u=d(du)=d(f'(t)dt)=df'(t)dt+f'(t)d(dt)=f''(t)dt^2+f'(t)d^2t.
$$
Basically, be very careful using tricks to 'cancel' second derivatives or differentials.  See [Cancellation rules for partial derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015067/cancellation-rules-for-partial-derivatives) for more details.

If you want further justification, see what happens if you try out your formula in a simple univariate case, like $u=t^2$ and $t=x^3$.